# How to disconnect the call before Twilio Video Room connect + CallKit iOS 13

Tags: xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, twilio, ios13, callkit

I need to disconnect a call before Twilio room connected. For that, we have implemented push notification we achieve but now **DidReceiveRemoteNotification** method is not calling when app is in background and kill states.

**Scenario:**

1. A calls B
2. A rejects B, then B is still ringing. To achieve this we used push notification but its not working. Making push notification working in background and kill state we made **content-available = 1 and enabled background modes** on in plist.

Please give any suggestions

Comment: Why aren't you using PushKit?

Comment: I used PushKit to receive incoming call with CallKit. Now the question is How can we disconnect the call after displaying Callkit default screen[For this we used normal push notification which not working in background and kill state]. Do we have any other alternative. Please suggest